# How to use Nodejs with R to get results

Tags: javascript, r, node.js

I am trying to use nodejs with R, how to Execute R algorithm via Node.Js and get the results.

Comment: And what attempts have you done? What did not work?

Comment: Maybe you could use https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: @edi9999 I think this is a bad idea. Maybe better OpenСPU?

Comment: Yes that maybe a better solution

Answer (score 2):

Check out [exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec), a node module to run terminal statements.

Example:

```
var exec = require('exec')

exec('code to run my R script', function(err, response) {
    if (err instanceof Error) throw err;

    if (err) {
        console.error('Something went wrong', err);
        process.stderr.write(err);
    }

    // R output
    console.log('All good', response);
    process.stdout.write(response);

    process.exit(1);
});
```

[`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is also a valid alternative. Checkout this: [Run R script and display graph using node.js](http://leapon.tumblr.com/post/10168944986/run-r-script-and-display-graph-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [OpenCPU](https://www.opencpu.org/) && [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/)
2. Install [node-opencpu](https://github.com/albertosantini/node-opencpu) client
3. Begin to use [OpenCPU API](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html)